# Shallow copy in 1-D list vs 2-D list

Tags: python, list, shallow-copy

I found lots of discussions related to "shallow copy" in Python, but I cannot find my exact issue.

As per my understanding, creating a shallow copy still contains references to the original values of the list. This holds true in following case of a two-dimensional list.

```
>>> x = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> y = list(x)
>>> x.append(['New value'])
>>> x
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ['New value']]
>>> y
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> x[0][0] = 'A'
>>> x
[['A', 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], ['New value']]
>>> y
[['A', 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Now, in one-dimensional list, I didn't find this effect.

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a.append(10)
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
>>> b
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> a[0] = 'A'
>>> a
['A', 2, 3, 4, 5, 10]
>>> b
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Can anyone please clarify what is behind this difference?

Comment: @mVChr: No, that is absolutely not how Python works. Lists and ints are treated the same.

Comment: That's not even close to true.

Comment: In the first case, you are mutating an object (the inner list) contained by your list. In the second case, you are mutating your list. So, try `x[0] = 'foo'` and you'll see the same behavior as your second case

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Shallow copy** copies the top-level items, making a new instance of each.  If there are any complex elements, the shallow copy will make a new copy of those items, but will *not* make new instances of *their* elements.  References to nested lists will be new, but the second-level references will still be for the original objects.

**Deep copy** makes a new instance of *each* element at *every* level.  One side effect is that this doubles the storage occupied by that item (now two items).

Here you can see the effect close-up.  The shallow copy, `b`, has its own copy of each top-level item; when we change `a[0]`, a scalar, the copy in `b` doesn't change.  Then, although `b[2]` is in a location different from `a[2]`, the pointer values are identical: they point to the same lower-level list.  Thus, when we change `a[2][1]`, that change is reflected in `b[2][1]`.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 4, 5]
>>> b = list(a)
>>> a[0] = "new 1"
>>> a[2][1] = "Deeper"
>>> a
['new 1', 2, ['a', 'Deeper', 'c'], 4, 5]
>>> b
[1, 2, ['a', 'Deeper', 'c'], 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thiking with C pointers. You're list is many adresses which include themself a list. You're only copiing a new instance of the entire list, but if you modify the content on the address that is included in your list will affect this list. **You're 3 three list inside x and inside y have the same address, but x and y have different addresses.**

```
x == 0x0123  #Hexadecimal addresses
y == 0x0456
x = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03, whatever_you_want]
y = [0x01, 0x02, 0x03]
0x01 = [1, 2, 3]
```

When we just assign to list together, if instead of `y = list(x)` you wrote `y = x`, x and y will be changed at the same time because they will be pointer to the same address, like `x = y = 0x0123`.

I'm not totally sure about all, but it's how I can uderstand it with my actual knowledge in C

Answer (score -2):

The lists in the list are references, so they share the same memory space even if you copy the outer list so that it doesn't. Notice that if you replace a list in the nested one it will only change in one and not the copy. Numbers aren't references, so when you copy a list they no longer share the same memory space

Comment: [If you examine the memory addresses with `id`](https://ideone.com/rOzdEj) (which, as a CPython implementation detail, returns the memory address of an object), you will find that the same address is given for ints in the original list or in a copy.

Comment: Numbers are references, *all objects are references, and everything is an object* Python doesn't have a "prinitive types" that work differently than other objects. The semantics are always the same.

Comment: Oh my god you guys. This is what I mean: `a = 2; b = 2; id(a) >>> 40923456; id(b) >>> 40923456` - yes it's a reference but the reference is always the same. Every time you make a new list it's a new reference (i.e. try the above with `[]` instead of `2`), but if you have two variables pointing to the same list if you modify an element of one you modify the element of the other.

Comment: No, the reference is *not* always the same. Python `int` objects work the exact same way in this context as list objects. Except that `int` objects don't expose any way to mutate them. Your explanation is simply incorrect. You have simply discovered a CPython implementation detail that small ints are cached. But try with larger ones, like 1000

Comment: [Here's an example with different addresses for equal ints](https://ideone.com/AL2mPc), just in case you try the 1000 example yourself and accidentally run into the *other* implementation detail (constant merging at bytecode compilation time) that would cause the experiment to give the same address. (For completeness, [here's](https://ideone.com/B4aFz1) the same example without avoiding constant merging.)